# Enumeration of labeled connected bipartite graphs given partite sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What would be the closed-form expression defining number of all possible labelled connected bipartite graphs given $\mid X \mid = m,  \mid Y \mid = n - m $?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, check out [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=connected+labeled+bipartite+graphs&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|X|=x, \ |Y|=y$.

There are $xy$ bipartite graphs, $(x-1)xy$ ways to selected a member of $X$ to be disconnected and form a bipartite graph with the remaining vertices, $(y-1)xy$ with a member of $y$ disconnected, $\frac{1}2xy(y-2)(y-1)$ with two members of $Y$ disconnected etc.

By inclusion-exclusion, the number of labelled connected bipartite graphs is

$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{n} {x\choose {i+1}}{y\choose{n-i+1}}$, for which there is unlikely to be any simple formula.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in Labeled Bipartite Blocks by F. Harary and R. W. Robinson (http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v31/cjm1979v31.0060-0068.pdf , page 63, formula 11):

$$C(m, n) = 2^{nm} - \sum{* \binom{n - 1}{a - 1} \binom{m}{b} 2^{(n - a)(m - b)} C(a, b) }.$$

The asterisk on the summation indicates conditions $1 \leq a \leq n$, $0 \leq b \leq m$, and either $a < n$ or $b < m$. The initial conditions are $R(0, 1) = 1$ and $R(0, n) = 0$ for $n \ne 1$, and it is obvious that $R(m, n) = R(n, m)$.